How to access the mesh of static variable in unity c#?
I have a problem the problem is this how can I access the mesh of the static variable in unity when the variable is in another script and I want to change the mesh in other script if i do not make it a static variable then it would not  work because it has two scenes one script is in the separate scene and the other is in the separate scene

if it truly is a static variable, then class.variable.whatever...

Although in this case your question is fairly clear, in future please don't forget to add some code to your qestions.
